# Import mathcal symbols from txfonts

Tags: fonts, math-mode

I would like to use the "`\mathcal` symbols" from [`txfonts`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/txfonts?lang=de), but otherwise use the standard symbols. Including the package `txfonts` changes all fonts, which I would like to avoid. The command

```
\DeclareSymbolFont{symbols}{OMS}{txsy}{m}{n}
```

uses all math symbols from `txfonts`, but I think that they are too thick (and the quantors look ugly), especially compared to the usual text font computer modern. Probably

```
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathcal}{T1}{TX}{m}{n}
```

should work, where TX has to be replaced by the correct family name of txfonts. Which is the correct one? I've already tried some names, but so far none has worked.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's as easy as this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathcal}{OMS}{ntxsy}{m}{n}   % or txsy
\SetMathAlphabet{\mathcal}{bold}{OMS}{ntxsy}{b}{n} % or txsy

\begin{document}
$x\mathcal{ABCDEF}y$

\boldmath$x\mathcal{ABCDEF}y$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Explanation. The TX/NewTX packages do no change to the basic math font setup, where `\mathcal` is defined by

```
\DeclareSymbolFontAlphabet{\mathcal}{symbols}
```

in order not to waste a math group. For your purpose a new math group is obviously necessary, so we just need to look in [`newtxmath.sty`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/fonts/newtx/tex/newtxmath.sty) what's the definition of the `symbols` math symbol font and we find

```
178 \DeclareSymbolFont{symbols}{OMS}{ntxsy}{m}{n}
179 \SetSymbolFont{symbols}{bold}{OMS}{ntxsy}{b}{n}
```

(line numbers added for reference). So it's sufficient to change `\DeclareSymbolFont{symbols}` with `\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathcal}` and `\SetSymbolFont{symbols}` with `\SetMathAlphabet{\mathcal}`.

It's better to use the fonts provided by NewTX that have refined metrics with respect to the older TX package and also is actively maintained, contrary to the old package.

Comment: So for this solution one needs newtx? I've already tried to install this before, but failed.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg You can use `txsy`, if you want, but my advice is to install a complete recent TeX distribution that has NewTX out of the box. Installing font packages over an old TeX distribution is always a PITA.

Comment: Ok. I had already tried to use "txsy", but just the encoding was wrong ...

Comment: Out of curiosity: Is it possible to use single symbols from txfont, for example, say, $\otimes$?

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg Yes, of course. Not really easy, but this question has the needed answers: [Importing a Single Symbol From a Different Font](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/14386). In case `\otimes` belongs to the `symbols` math group, the approach with `\DeclareSymbolFont` and `\DeclareSymbolFontAlphabet` will become necessary in order not to waste math groups.

Answer (score 3):

The standard definition of `\mathcal` is in `fontmath.ltx`:

```
\DeclareSymbolFontAlphabet{\mathcal}   {symbols}
```

So, to use a different font, we need to do two things:

- define a new symbol font, with a distinct name (because we don't want everything else to come from the `txfonts` `symbol` font);
- redefine `\mathcal` so that it uses the new font.

So, let's use `symbolstx` for the new font. Looking for the definition of `symbols` in `txfonts.sty`, we find:

```
\DeclareSymbolFont{symbols}{OMS}{txsy}{m}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{symbols}{bold}{OMS}{txsy}{bx}{n}
```

So, we just need to adapt these lines to specify `symbolstx` rather than `symbols`:

```
\DeclareSymbolFont{symbolstx}{OMS}{txsy}{m}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{symbolstx}{bold}{OMS}{txsy}{bx}{n}
```

Then we can define `\mathcal` accordingly:

```
\DeclareSymbolFontAlphabet{\mathcal}{symbolstx}
```

Putting it altogether:

```
\documentclass{article}

\DeclareSymbolFont{symbolstx}{OMS}{txsy}{m}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{symbolstx}{bold}{OMS}{txsy}{bx}{n}

\DeclareSymbolFontAlphabet{\mathcal}{symbolstx}

\begin{document}

  \[
    \mathcal{ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ}
  \]

\end{document}
```

[image: modified calligraphic maths]

Comment: Three lines instead of just two. `;-)`. But it's better to use `ntxsy`, which has better metrics.

Comment: @egreg But is not what the OP asked for ;). Not that it isn't true....